# What JSRs does the Spring Framework use?

Tags: java, spring, specifications, jsr

I'm trying to understand what jsr-s Spring uses. In the documentation of Spring there are jsr-340, jsr-356, jsr-236, jsr-367, jsr-303, jsr-338, jsr-330, jsr-250, jsr for JTA, jsr for JCA and that's all. However there is JSR for JMX and there is Spring JMX. Does Spring uses this JSR? I need to know the list of all JSR-s Spring uses. Thank's in advance.

Comment: JMX module offers two FactoryBean implementations inside the
org.springframework.jmx.support package for creating both server- and client-side connectors which uses JSR-160. I suggest to refer the spring reference document which does have all the details. https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/5.0.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/pdf/spring-framework-reference.pdf